# RabbitMQ - How to reuse the same connection with multiple channels

Tags: php, rabbitmq, amqp, php-amqplib

I am trying to master some best practices for RabbitMQ. My goal is to create a single connection, and then, using on this single connection, create multiple channels on this connection.

Following the RabbitMQ and php-amqplib documentation, creating a new connection looks like this.

```
$newConnection = new AMQPStreamConnection('localhost', 5672, 'guest', 'guest');
$newChannel = $newConnection->channel($channel_id);
```

The code continues on with

```
while ($this->channel->is_consuming()) {
    $this->channel->wait();
}
```

I have this code saved on a file, test.php. I then proceed to open two terminal sessions, and on each, run the following

```
php test.php
```

I can see that both the channels are open and waiting. However, when I access RabbitMQ's management UI page, and click on connections tab, I can see there are 2 connections listed, each having 1 channel. I am hoping to see only 1 connection, with 2 channels.

Answer (score 0):

you have to try something with loop of channels and `$channel->wait(null, true);`. Second parameters is `$non_blocking` and default is `false`.

Comment: Do you have any working code samples I could look at? Thanks!